# Failing to build PX4 with catkin build

Tags: ros, px4, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use PX4 launch files (mavros_posix_sitl.launch) with GAZEBO simulator, but I can't build PX4 as a ROS package.

I am using ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

I installed PX4 inside ~/catkin_ws/src using:

```
git clone https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot.git --recursive
```

When I try to build catkin, I get the following error:
[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2020-12-14 11-27-58.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/16080205285503115.png)

What is wrong?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367756/failing-to-build-px4-with-catkin-build/) by [Naza karim](https://answers.ros.org/users/52156/naza-karim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-12-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are not supposed to build PX4 as a ROS package.

You are supposed to build it using `make` using the command `make px4_sitl_default gazebo` if you want to use it with Gazebo and then just source the setup files and put PX4 in the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

All the instructions are there in the official documentation of PX4.

---

Originally posted by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) with karma: 277 on 2021-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1